# Repeating animation with execute function and UI update

Tags: ios, swift, function, animation, uiviewanimation

I am making a game like AdVenture Capitalist and i am encountering this problem.

I have one label that has just text in it, that label never changes.
I have one animated label that has the same origin as the previous one, which on button pressed is animated as a loading bar.
I have one label which displays the sum when function is executed.
I have one button, when pressed it executes the animation.
I have a function that sums two numbers.
And I have a function that updates the label where sum of previous function is show.
My problem is this, when I make my code execute this only once everything works as planed, but when I try to make it an infinite loop it will not work.

```
func animate(){
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animation{
              self.animated.frame.size.width += 200
              self.animated.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
             }, completion: {
            (end: Bool)->Void in
            self.animated.frame.size.width = 0
            self.sumFunc()
            self.updateLabel()
            })
```

This code works just fine, but when i try and make it an infinite loop like this it doesn't work.

```
func animateInfinite(){
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
      self.animated.frame.size.width += 200
      self.animated.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
      // when I put sumFunc here and updateFunc here, the app breaks, and will not compile
     }, completion: {
            (end: Bool)->Void in
        // when I put sumFunc here and updateFunc here, the app runs, but it never executes, because I have noticed that .repeat animation never has a completion.
```

I have also tried to make the tasks execute in different threads, but I haven't been successful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourClass  {

 var isAnimationStop = false

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  startanimation()
 }

 func startanimation(){
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
   self.animated.frame.size.width += 10
   self.animated.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
   }, completion: {_ in
   self.animated.frame.size.width = 0
   if !self.isAnimationStop{
     self. startanimation()
     self.sumFunc()
     self.updateLabel()
   }
  })
 }

// call stop when you want
 func stopAnimation()  {
  self.isAnimationStop = true
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't thought about calling the startAnimation() function in the competition! Thank you again.